# Making call to Rest services in mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-module-jpa, mule-cluster

I have made a web app which call mule server which is listening to http inbound point  at 8081 for accessing the database.I am accessing the database successfully and getting a message. But I want to access the other rest services after I get the object from the database and run some operations.
I don't know how to achieve this.

Please give me example. I am posting my flow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" method="POST" name="HTTP" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="root" password="123456" database="Customer" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <flow name="muleesbintegrationFlow1" doc:name="muleesbintegrationFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   path="crud" doc:name="HTTP" ref="HTTP"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="input" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.input]" doc:name="input"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="cid" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.cid]" doc:name="cid"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="fname" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.fname]" doc:name="fname"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="lname" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.fname]" doc:name="lname"/>
        <choice doc:name="ChoicerOfCrud">
            <when expression="#[sessionVars['input']== &quot;insert&quot;]">
                <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="insert">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO `Customer`.`customer` (`customer_id`, `fname`, `lname`) VALUES (#[sessionVars['cid']], #[sessionVars['fname']],  #[sessionVars['lname']]);]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:insert>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[sessionVars['input']]==&quot;update&quot;]">
                <db:update config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="update">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[UPDATE `Customer`.`customer`  set 
fname =  #[sessionVars['fname']],
lname=  #[sessionVars['lname']]
where customer_id = #[sessionVars['cid']];]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:update>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[sessionVars['input']==&quot;select&quot;]">
                <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="selected">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Customer.customer where customer_id =#[sessionVars['cid']];]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:select>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <db:delete config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="delete">
                    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[DELETE FROM `Customer`.`customer` WHERE `customer_id`=#[sessionVars['cid']];]]></db:dynamic-query>
                </db:delete>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to call an outbound http endpoint after your crud operation?

Comment: What type of result is your web-app expecting from your Mule service? JSON? XML?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use http:outbound-endpoint to consume a REST service (GET,POST, PUT or DELETE). In this example you can see a flow to invoke a services GET:

```
<flow name="invoke-ws" doc:name="invoke-ws">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="vm-ws" doc:name="VM"/>
    <logger message="payload is: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://ip:port/service/#[payload]" doc:name="HTTP">
        <set-property propertyName="Accept" value="application/json"/>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger message="payload is: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
</flow>
```

If the service is SOAP over HTTP, I recommend using http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer

Comment: Hey sorry @julio What you didn't get my question.Did u see my flow.I am doing crud operation in database.After that crud operation The database return Object.After that I want my database object to hit some service.But the issue is I am unable to understand how can I perform.My first request is come for a web app made in String mvc and I want that I result should go back to that app.Please help me.

Comment: When you run the operation in database, you can manipulate the object to convert in a json or xml document, changing the payload. Then you can include a vm transport : request-reponse to invoke the flow in the example provided.

Comment: @Manoj your comment above is very difficult to understand, could you please clarify further? Are you trying to use the results from your database call to send to a web-service consumer? Shouldn't your just return the database results as your [Payload](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/set-payload-transformer-reference)?